# How to implement a custom tail recursive map for lists in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to implement a function called map that receives a list and a function and the yields the result of applying the function to each element of the input list.
So I have this so far:

```
def map(list: List[Int], function: (Int) => Int): List[Int] = {
  def loop(list: List[Int], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    list match {
      case Nil => acc
      case head :: tail => loop(list.tail, function(head) :: acc)
    }
  }
  loop(list.reverse, Nil)
}
```

This code works and gives me the expected result, but I cannot help thinking there is a more elegant and efficient way that doesn't involve using `reverse` or another list method that isn't `head` or `tail`.

Comment: No, it is not. You had three options: **1)** Two tail-recursive traverses over the list _(what you did, however it is more common to reverse the list at the end)_. **2)** Traverse the list once with a non-tail recursive function that can blow up your stack. **3)** Use mutation and a standard while loop to achieve stack safety and only one traverse _(that is what the implementation of the standard library does)_. - Well, you can also implement `map` in terms of other functions, like `flatMap`, `foldLeft`, `foldRight`. But, all of these converge to the previous three cases.

Answer (score 8):

As far as rolling your own implementation of a *purely functional* `map` function, without using any mutable state or built-in `List` *higher-order functions*, you've done a great job! Having to `reverse` the list does seem unnecessary, but it's worth it because prepending to a list is a very efficient operation.

As well as the other methods suggested in the comments, you could make `acc` a `scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer` (which supports efficient append and prepend operations), then converting it to a list when you're done. However, the conversion process isn't a great improvement over `reverse`.

Otherwise, there are a few minor things you can do to improve your `map` function:

- By using curried arguments, you can use `map` more elegantly.
- Functions that need to be *tail-recursive* should *always* be decorated with the `scala.annotation.tailrec` attribute. The *Scala* compiler then knows your intention, and will issue an error if the function cannot be optimized to use tail recursion.
- It's trivial to make this function generic, which will make it far more widely useful.
- It's generally more idiomatic to perform the `reverse` operation on the result. It makes no difference for a *map* operation, but if you were to write a *filter* operation, for example, then it would be more efficient to reverse the potentially smaller set of filtered elements.

Here's how that would then look:

```scala
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def map[A, B](list: List[A])(function: (A) => B): List[B] = {

  @tailrec
  def loop(rem: List[A], acc: List[B]): List[B] = rem match {
    case Nil => acc.reverse
    case head :: tail => loop(tail, function(head) :: acc)
  }
  loop(list, Nil)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `head :: tail` is the most efficient way to deconstruct and reconstruct a `List`, what you've done is a pretty common pattern. The `.reverse` is unfortunate but usually amounts to a minor performance penalty.

As mentioned in the comments, `map` can also be implemented via other Standard Library methods. Here it's done with `foldRight`:

```
def map(list :List[Int], function :Int => Int) :List[Int] = 
  list.foldRight(List.empty[Int])(function(_) :: _)
```